# Cmake not changing build flags

Tags: cmake, fortran

Consider the following simple openMP program:

```
program hello
    use OMP_LIB
    implicit none
    integer   :: nthreads, tid

    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(nthreads, tid)
    tid = omp_get_thread_num()
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
    ! print *, "hello"
    print *,"Thread:", tid, "of", nthreads
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
end program hello
```

when i compile it as

> gfortran -fopenmp hello.90 -o hello.x

I get output as:

> Thread:           2 of           4
>
> Thread:           1 of           4
>
> Thread:           0 of           4
>
> Thread:           3 of           4

as expected.

Now if i consider the following `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (hello Fortran)
enable_language(Fortran)

IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  message("NO BUILD TYPE PROVIDED")
  message("DEFAULT BUILD TYPE SET TO 'Release'")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE 'Release')
ENDIF()
IF(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES RELEASE OR ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES Release)
  message("MAKING RELEASE BUILD")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-fopenmp")
  message("FLAGS: ${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
ENDIF()

add_executable(hello.x hello.f90)
```

Considering above file is right, it should add omp flag to make file and hence compile and run same, however

```
$ mkdir build; cd build
$ cmake ..
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 6.1.0
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether Fortran compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/local/bin/gfortran - works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/local/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 - yes
NO BUILD TYPE PROVIDED
DEFAULT BUILD TYPE SET TO 'Release'
MAKING RELEASE BUILD
FLAGS: -fopenmp
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/user/Programs/omp/build

$
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target hello.x
[ 50%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/hello.x.dir/hello.f90.o
[100%] Linking Fortran executable hello.x
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_omp_get_num_threads_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in hello.f90.o
  "_omp_get_thread_num_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in hello.f90.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [hello.x] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello.x.dir/all] Error 2
```

Which is same as missing `-fopenmp` flag. How to add it?

Comment: Please do not link to external files that may become inaccessible at any time. Copy  and paste the content here. It is not even that long. Just do copy and paste.

Comment: Note, that `cmake -LA` shows only CACHE'd variables. You set "normal" variable `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE`, so it isn't stored in the cache. However, such variable setting should work... provided you have correctly set it. You show so a little code, so it is difficult to say what is wrong. Please, create [mcve] and add it to the question post (not as link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` command for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` take a "non-string" argument apparently.

Changing

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE 'Release')
```

to

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
```

solved the problem for me. I first dug into the cache system to understand why your setting would not work and there was no reason. I found a `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_'Release'` entry in ccmake and looked again at the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in the docs, and it takes values `empty, Debug, Release, RelWithDebInfo, MinSizeRel` (which I understood as being unquoted).

Comment: Explicit BUILD_TYPE to Release does make it behave properly. Is there any reason? I mean I am setting build type to `Release` in line 5-9 of Cmake file anyway. What difference would explicit build type make? And any suggestion on how to automate it?

Comment: My bad, the solution was even easier. Updating.

Comment: Yes that was the issue apparently. I am not sure why though, because I have been using it on another machine and there it worked with strings too i believe (i imported it as project in CLion and it correctly got all flags). And am sure i picked it up from some accepted answer from SO only! anyhow, thank you for your answer